# Finding parent node in binary search tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I am getting answer as 0 for a node. While printing the searches I am able to see the path however it is not returning the data of node.
Following is the code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None

    def insert(self,ele):
        p=Node(ele)
        if self.root is None:
            self.root=p
            return
        q=self.root
        while(q is not None):
            if ele<=q.data:
                if q.left is None:    
                    q.left=p
                    return
                else:
                    q=q.left
            else:
                if q.right is None:
                    q.right=p
                    return
                else:
                    q=q.right

    def inorder(self,x):
        if x is not None:
            self.inorder(x.left)
            print(x.data,end='-')
            self.inorder(x.right)

    def preorder(self,x):
        if x is not None:
            print(x.data,end='-')
            self.preorder(x.left)
            self.preorder(x.right)

    def postorder(self,x):
        if x is not None:
            self.postorder(x.left)
            self.postorder(x.right)
            print(x.data,end='-')

    def father(self,x,ele):
        if self.root is None:
            return 'Tree Empty'
        x=self.root
        if ele==x.data:
            return 'Root Node'
        while (x is not None):
            if x.left==ele or x.right==ele:
                return x.data
            if ele<=x.data:
                x=x.left
            else:
                x=x.right
        return 0
```

Calling:

```
b=BinarySearchTree()
b.insert(45)
b.insert(41)
b.insert(79)
b.insert(90)
b.insert(10)
b.insert(88)
b.insert(92)
b.insert(19)
print('--------------------------------------')
print('Inorder Traversal :')
b.inorder(b.root)
print('\n------------------------------------')
print('\nPreorder Traversal :')
b.preorder(b.root)
print('\n------------------------------------')
print('\nPostorder Traversal :')
b.postorder(b.root)
print('\n------------------------------------')
ele=int(input('Enter element to find father of:'))
z=b.father(b.root,ele)
print('Father of '+str(ele)+' is '+str(z))
print('\n------------------------------------')
```

I cannot write as `x.left.data==ele or x.right.data==ele` while comparing with element. any suggestion(Consider Insertion is properly implemented)?

The output snippet is:

```
--------------------------------------
Inorder Traversal :
10-19-41-45-79-88-90-92-
------------------------------------

Preorder Traversal :
45-41-10-19-79-90-88-92-
------------------------------------

Postorder Traversal :
19-10-41-88-92-90-79-45-
------------------------------------
Enter element to find father of:88
Father of 88 is 0

-----------------------------------
```

Answer should be 90

```
    45
   /  \
  41   79
 /      \
10       90
\       / \
 19    88  92
```

Comment: The question isn't really clear, can you add an example of what the input and output should be

Comment: Updated the question @DeveshKumarSingh. Output snippet and tree is posted.

Comment: @BhupeshPatil, welcome to SO ! Usually people expect code that can just be copied and pasted and make it run. Here we need to create the tree ourselves, which is not very helpful

Comment: I have created every function required (insertion,inorder,preorder,postorder). Just didn't posted it because they are working properly (Should I post it ?). I just needed help with this father(). @BlueSheepToken

Comment: Father (i assume you mean parent) is of 88 is 90, why should the answer be 79?

Comment: Oh  yes sorry . 90 it is

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `ele` is a value for which you're searching for the corresponding node in the tree, so you cannot compare it with `left` or `right` nodes because they are of different types. If this is correct, then simply 'de-reference' the children:

```
def father(self,x,ele):
    if self.root is None:
        return 'Tree Empty'

    x = self.root
    if ele == x.data:
        return 'Root Node'

    while (x is not None):
      node = x.left
      if node.data == ele:
          return x.data
      node = x.right
         return x.data
      if ele <= x.data:
          x = x.left
      else:
          x = x.right
```

Additionally this seems like a trivial fix through a debugger. Fire up `pdb` and set a breakpoint just inside `father`. For example:

```
python -m pdb your_tree_script.py
-> <first executable line of your script output by pdb>
(Pdb) break <line number of first line in father function input by you>
...
```

see [pdb — The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) for available commands.